# Pyro4 Encoding in JSON/Base64

Tags: python, json, network-programming, remoteobject, pyro

So I have a simple application using Pyro4 (Python Remote Objects). There is an exposed class `API`, and I have a file that calls the function `api.parse(input,userid)`, which returns some JSON dependent on input. However, instead of simply returning the result as a string (which it did previously), it returns `{'data': 'eyJlcnJvciI6ICJDb21tYW5kIG5vdCByZWNvZ25pc2VkIn0=', 'encoding': 'base64'}`
, where the base64 is the JSON string that `parse` should returned.

I'm very confused as to why this is not working - I have tested it previously and there was no issue, the string was just returned with no weird base64 encoding. Only thing I can think of is I have changed networks (School connection to home connection) but I don't think this should be a problem? I have prepared an MVE of some code that indicates the problem.

#### testserver.py

```
import Pyro4;
import json;

@Pyro4.expose
class API:
    def parse(self,buff,userid):
        return prep({"error":"Command not recognised"});

def prep(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj).encode("utf-8");

# Pyro stuff
daemon = Pyro4.Daemon()                # make a Pyro daemon
ns = Pyro4.locateNS()                  # find the name server
uri = daemon.register(API)   # register the greeting maker as a Pyro object
ns.register("testAPI", uri)   # register the object with a name in the name server
daemon.requestLoop()
```

#### testclient.py

```
import Pyro4;
import json;

api = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:testAPI");
resp = api.parse("whatever","something");
print(resp); # Produces {'data': 'eyJlcnJvciI6ICJDb21tYW5kIG5vdCByZWNvZ25pc2VkIn0=', 'encoding': 'base64'}
# I just want b'{"error":"Command not recognised"}'
```

Note - Printing at the stage where `prep` is applied in `parse()` gives the expected result `b'{"error":"Command not recognised"}'`. I'm using the command `python3 -m Pyro4.naming` to start the nameserver if that matters as well. I'm thinking there's probably some global setting/constant I haven't set correctly or something - All responses welcome, thankyou!

Comment: Also just a note - yes I could just decode the base64 string but I want to know *why* it's doing this (And if I write code to decode base64 and it switches back I'll have to re-debug it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default serialization protocol that Pyro uses is serpent, and that is a text-based protocol. This means it cannot transmit binary data (bytes) unless it encodes them to a text format, which it does in the way you discovered.

There's a little helper function (`serpent.tobytes`) available that you could use in your client code that automatically detects and converts the response if needed, see the info box in this paragraph in the manual: https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/tipstricks.html?highlight=base64#binary-data-transfer-file-transfer

Ofcourse, if you make the data sent by your server strings in the first place, there's no need for this. (This can't be done if the data really *is* binary though, such as an image or sound clip or whatever)

In your case with the json text it gets transformed into *bytes* if you `encode` it. As you discovered there is no need for this at all, just leave it as a string and you won't run into issues. (which leaves me with the question why you're still doing the encode to utf-8  bytes in your client?)

Comment: Thanks for the clearer and more detailed answer. The data is later sent over a socket connection (which needs bytes) , so I wanted to do all the processing in a single step.

Comment: Ok, there's one other thing: why are you json-encoding at all in your server? Just return the response object as-is, and let the client decide what to do with it!

Comment: It's slightly more complicated. I have this server/client configuration, which then sends to another client. Eg: Datastore ---(Pyro)---> Frontend ---(Socket)---> Client, hence why I'm not just using the RMI object directly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Pyro doesn't like trying to send raw bytes - It'd rather convert the bytes to base64 then send it as JSON. So to fix, I changed:

```
def prep(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj).encode("utf-8");
```

to

```
def prep(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj);
```

And put the encode bit in the client.